# Select rows with interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intervals

I have a wide Pandas dataframe with TimeIndexed values and I wanted to select with an Interval object that I made:

```
inter = pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2017-12-05 16:36:17'),
                    pd.Timestamp('2017-12-05 22:00:00'), closed='left')
```

I tried loc and iloc method but they don't accept Interval instance as argument.

I can test if a Timestamp is in that Interval that way:

```
pd.Timestamp('2017-12-05 22:00:00') in inter
```

But I'm not able to write a line to select the row of the dataframe.

Comment: One approach `df.loc[inter.left:inter.right]`, although this won't respect `closed='left'` or `closed='right'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Setup**

```
s = pd.Series(
      pd.date_range('2017-12-05 16:00:00', '2017-12-05 23:00:00', freq='H')
)
s

0   2017-12-05 16:00:00
1   2017-12-05 17:00:00
2   2017-12-05 18:00:00
3   2017-12-05 19:00:00
4   2017-12-05 20:00:00
5   2017-12-05 21:00:00
6   2017-12-05 22:00:00
7   2017-12-05 23:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Here's how to solve this problem, for *all 4 cases* of interval inclusion.

1. `closed='left'`

   ```
   (inter.left <= s) & (s < inter.right)

   0    False
   1     True
   2     True
   3     True
   4     True
   5     True
   6    False
   7    False
   dtype: bool
   ```
2. `closed='right'`

   ```
   (inter.left < s) & (s <= inter.right)

   0    False
   1     True
   2     True
   3     True
   4     True
   5     True
   6     True
   7    False
   dtype: bool
   ```
3. `closed='neither'`

   ```
   (inter.left < s) & (s < inter.right)

   0    False
   1     True
   2     True
   3     True
   4     True
   5     True
   6    False
   7    False
   dtype: bool
   ```
4. `closed='both'` (use `pd.Series.between`, should be slightly more efficient).

   ```
   s.between(inter.left, inter.right, inclusive=True) 

   0    False
   1     True
   2     True
   3     True
   4     True
   5     True
   6     True
   7    False
   dtype: bool
   ```

After computing these quantities using any of these methods, selecting rows is as easy `s[mask]` where `mask` is the boolean mask we've just computed above.

Comment: I really like this answer. This is a great explanation. +2 if you finish it up with `loc` or `mask`

Comment: this must be very fast!

Comment: @MaxU I think it should be. `between` should be even better (I'm hoping... haven't tested, haha).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, you must've just added it ;) haha.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ my testing also shows that `between` is MUCH faster

Comment: But, I'm looking for a builtin method to pass an Intervall directly. If there is not, maybe I should wright according to your exemple.

Comment: @Adri There isn't any such builtin besides `pd.Series.between`, but that only handles one of the 4 possible cases that may arise. And nothing yet to handle interval objects directly, as-is.

Comment: Anyidea on how to write this method clearly ? I'm trying but I failed. It should and Interval argument in input and return a mask

Comment: @Adri For any followup questions, you can write a new post with your new problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example I have. We can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and I will walk you through it step by step:

```
import pandas as pd
inter = pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2017-12-05 16:36:17'),
                    pd.Timestamp('2017-12-05 22:00:00'), closed='left')
# creating a dataframe of different dates ranging from 12/03 to 12/07
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Dates':pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2017-12-03 16:36:17'), 
      pd.Timestamp('2017-12-07 22:00:00'), freq='H')})

# creating a column to see if the data is in between the interval you created.
df3['In?'] = df3['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x in inter)

#filtering that dataframe 
df3.loc[df3['In?'] ==True]
```

Now you can probably skip the creating of the `In?` column and just do the filtering straight away, but I wanted you to see the steps

`df3.loc[df3['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x in inter) == True]` is how to do it without creating `in` using the `apply()` method

Comment: Try this one: `df3.query("@inter.left <= Dates < @inter.right")` - it should be faster than `.apply`

Comment: @MaxU `apply()` got `100 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop` where `query()` got `100 loops, best of 3: 2.23 ms per loop`. Interesting

Comment: try to test it on bigger DF's: `df3 = pd.concat([df3]*1000, ignore_index=True)` ;-)

Comment: @MaxU. Slightly... `524 ms per loop` vs `4.16 ms per loop` haha. cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution results `2 ms per loop` for the digger x1000 dataframe

Comment: yeah, i've added timing for all three options... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing sample data set from @MattR's answer:

```
In [114]: df3.query("@inter.left <= Dates < @inter.right")
Out[114]:
                 Dates
48 2017-12-05 16:36:17
49 2017-12-05 17:36:17
50 2017-12-05 18:36:17
51 2017-12-05 19:36:17
52 2017-12-05 20:36:17
53 2017-12-05 21:36:17
```

Timings for ~100K rows DF:

```
In [109]: df = pd.concat([df3]*1000, ignore_index=True)

In [110]: df.shape
Out[110]: (102000, 1)

In [111]: %timeit df.query("@inter.left <= Dates < @inter.right")
9.1 ms ± 20.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [112]: %timeit df.loc[df['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x in inter) == True]
1.54 s ± 48.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [113]: %timeit df[df['Dates'].between(inter.left, inter.right, inclusive=True)]
3.96 ms ± 43.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```